# apache configuration to make IE play m4a files

Tags: apache-2.2, audio, html5

I have an apache configuration problem that I hope someone will shed some light on, i have a test page with html5 audio tag pointing to an m4a file on my server, all browsers except for IE are able to play this file although in the mimetypes, audio/mpeg mp1 mp2 mp3 m4a are defined. Strangely enough, if i change the extension of the file to .mp4, IE will play the audio. Any hint about that?

Comment: Is the m4a defined as `audio/mp4`?

Comment: no, but i defined it now and no effect